# websocket from javascript with additional Authorization header

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I had a plain webSocket using JavaScript connecting to server and i want to add authorization header (bearer)

I tried to do it using plain but I had no option to do this

after googling this I found a library called [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/docs/v4/index.html), I tried to use it and succeed to create the same http request but can't connect to server

after reading some documentation I found that to make the socket.io client work the server must be made using socket.io too but I can't change server

I tried [robust-webSocket](https://github.com/appuri/robust-websocket) but it also use plain webSocket so I couldn't add headers

is there any other solution for this problem?